# how to retrive markers from firebase (real database) to new google maps api in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

**below function to get markers from firebase real database by (For loops)and this function i call it from markers parameter in google map or google map created but its not show marker from database so how to do this**

```
_getMarkers()async{
    final locationReference=FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users');

    final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$_markerIdCounter';
    _markerIdCounter++;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

    for(var items in locationReference.child("path")){
      _markers2.add(Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: LatLng(items.longitude,items.latitude),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "${items.restaurantname}"),
        onTap: () {
          _onMarkerTapped(markerId);
        },
        onDragEnd: (LatLng position) {
          _onMarkerDragEnd(markerId, position);
        },

      ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is your firebase code?

Comment: the code is updated please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not retrieving anything from the realtime database, you have to use `once()` to retrieve:

```
    final locationReference=FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users');
     locationReference.once().then((result){
          print(result.value);
        });
```

Comment: ok , but how for loops to get values and set this values in marker when am added it in google maps

Comment: u need to retrieve the markers from ur database, what does this `print(result.value);` give you?

Comment: when use for(var items in result)                                               
 {                                                                                           
 print(result.value);                                                                                             
 }                                                                                             
 Terminator error when am run:                                             
  the type DataSnapShot used in the 'for' loop must implement iterable

Comment: what does this print `print(result.value);`?

Comment: just print in terminal all information from database ok great in this step  but when am use this result in marker not support me examble : new marker(markerId: result.value? , position: LatLng(result.value,result.value), how can do here ;) you understand me? :)

Comment: my problem its solved now by some updates some parts from u first answer and other plus adds , thanks